# How do I write a text file from within a C# ASP.NET page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm coming to C# ASP.NET from Ruby and PHP, and I'm enjoying some elements of it but am finding certain things difficult to achieve. It's a bit different to get my head around, and I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me get this bit up and running.

I am trying to take some text sent in a POST request, HTML-escape it, and then write it to a text file.

So I look it up, read a little, and try:

```
<% 
    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Server.MapPath(@"./messager.txt"));
    file.WriteLine(Request.Form["message"]);
    file.Close();
%>
```

Not doing the HTML-escaping yet, just trying to actually write to the text file.

This doesn't work, though; it throws no error that I can see, but just does nothing, the text file isn't written to at all. I've researched the methods and can't really figure out why. I would really love some help.

If it helps, here is working Ruby code for what I am trying to do:

```
File.open "messager.txt", "w" {|f| f.puts h params[:message]}
```

Comment: Did you try a backslash (\\) in the path instead of forward slash (/)?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @FabrizioAccatino I'm not getting an error; the text file simply isn't being written to.

Comment: @dotNET I've just tried that, unfortunately with no change. It's worth pointing out that `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(@"~\messager.txt"))` *does* work so I don't think the path ist he problem.

Comment: I would recommend to do that in code behind since it is not ruby or  php or asp. asp.net isn't meant to be used like this.

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide a virtual path relative to the web app when using `Server.MapPath` using the special character `~` which is a shortcut to the web app root directory. Now, the simplest way to do it is a follows...

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~\messager.txt"), Request.Form["message"]);
```

this is assuming that the request actually contains the "message" form variable. Note that this approach will create a new file if it doesn't exist or will override it if it does exist.

However, in ASP.NET Web Forms we usually use server controls such as a `TextBox`, if when posting the page the message is set to a text box, then a better way to retrieve this message in OOP-style would be...

```
TextBox_ID.Text;
```

where `TextBox_ID` is the id of the TextBox

#### Edit

if `Request.Form["message"]` is coming in empty. Make sure that:

1. there's a text input element named `message`
2. there's no other element with the same `name` attribute
3. the input element is inside the `form` tag with `runat=server` attribute
4. you are posting back the page instead of issuing a GET request

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I appreciate it. I've tried using the code sample you provided, but it doesn't work; nothing is written to the text file. This makes me think something is wrong with the way I'm posting data. I am sending a simple HTML form, where a text input element named 'message' is submitted to the page this ASP.NET code is embedded on. Is `Request.Form["message"]` not the correct way to access information sent in this way?